# How to exchange RichTextBox Contents to HTML

Tags: html, wpf, richtextbox

I want to exchange `RichTextBoxContents` to HTML.

I used `aspose.word`, but it was demo version.
ex)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAsEh.png)

Comment: what do you want to do? Display HTML content in your WPF application?
If this is the case use a `WebBrowser-Control`

Comment: No I want to save the input of RichTextBox as an html file

Comment: Just look a bit into how HTML works and you should be able to write your own parser pretty easy just a few <p> and <h> should do the trick for something basic as a rtb

Comment: Thanks I got a rough sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should guide you in a rough direction:

```
string output = "";
Foreach( line in richtextbox.text)
{
  output += $"<p style=\"color:{line.color.name};\">"
  output += line
  ouput += "</p>";
}
```

should give you something like this:

```
<p style="color:red;">This is a the line content.</p>
```

I'm on my phone so have mercy if the syntax is a little bit off

Comment: In fact, thanks to your hint, I was able to successfully code. 
I really appreciate it.